# How to get tag ID using MFRC522 and ESP8266 NodeMCU 0.1

Tags: rfid, esp8266, nodemcu

I am using an ESP8266 NodeMCU v0.1 and MFRC RC522. Please can anyone tell me how I can send the tag ID to my web server and how to connect NodeMCU to RC522?

Comment: "how I can send the tag ID to my web server" - which protocol? HTTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to use this example with few modifications. 
https://github.com/Jorgen-VikingGod/ESP8266-MFRC522

Wiring as follows:

```
SDA(SS) - D4 (GPIO2)
SCK     - D5 (GPIO14) (hw spi)
MOSI    - D7 (GPIO13) (hw spi)
MISO    - D6 (GPIO12) (hw spi)
IRQ     - 
GND     - G
RST     - D3 (GPIO0) (FLASH)
3.3V    - 3V
```

And in the code I have redefined these variables:

```
#define RST_PIN  D3
#define SS_PIN   D4
```

Worked for me.